# Magento1.9 CSV generate but not download on save action

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, csv, programmatically, download

Here is my controller code ::

```
public function saveAction()
        {
            $post_data=$this->getRequest()->getPost();
            if ($post_data) {

                try {
                    $orderId = 1;
                    $order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($orderId);
                    $header = array('Order Id','Product Name','Sku','Price'); 
                    $io = new Varien_Io_File();
                    $path = Mage::getBaseDir('var') . DS . 'export' . DS;
                    $name = 'file-'.$orderId.'.csv';
                    $file = $path . DS . $name;
                    $io->setAllowCreateFolders(true);
                    $io->open(array('path' => $path));
                    $io->streamOpen($file, 'w+');
                    $io->streamLock(true);
                    $io->streamWriteCsv($header);

                    $items = $order->getAllItems();
                    foreach ($items as $item) {
                        $data = array($order->getIncrementId(), $item->getName(), $item->getSku(), $item->getPrice()); 
                        $io->streamWriteCsv($data); 
                    }
                    $io->streamUnlock();
                    $io->streamClose();
                    // Download
                    $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($name, file_get_contents($file));
                    $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($this->__('File downloaded.'));
                } 
                catch (Exception $e) {
                    Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->addError($e->getMessage());
                    Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->setExampleData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
                    $this->_redirect("*/*/edit", array("id" => $this->getRequest()->getParam("id")));
                    return;
                }

            }
            $this->_redirect("*/*/");
        }
```

**$this->_prepareDownloadResponse - Download function but not working direct redirect with success message but file not download.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got issue. here is solution

```
1. you need to prepare array insted of `file_get_contents($file)`
like below
                      $csv = Array(
                            'type' => 'filename',
                            'value' => $file,
                            'rm' => '1'
                        );


2. change this function .

    old - $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($name, file_get_contents($file));
    new - $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($name, $csv);
```

Now it's works!!!!